# Display SQL results in columns instead of a several lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

ProfilRights:

```
ProfilRightId    ProfilId    AccessId     Right 
-------------    --------    --------    --------    
      1             1           1           full  
      2             1           2           r-o
      3             2           1           none
      4             2           2           full
```

Profil table:

```
    ProfilId    ProfilName    
    --------    ----------    
       1           IT            
       2           Admin
```

Access table:

```
        AcessId       AcessName    
        --------      ----------    
           1          Employess
           2          Clients
```

Translation table for Acess:
AccessTranslation

```
   AccessTransId   AcessId       TranslatedLabel   Language
   -------------   --------      ---------------   -------- 
         1           1           Employees         English
         2           2           Clients           English
         3           1           EmployeesFR       French
         4           2           ClientsFR         French
```

I want the results to be displayed in the following way:

```
    EnglishAcess    FrenchAcess     IT        Admin
    -------------    --------      ------     ------
    Employees        EmployeesFR   full        none    
    Clients          ClientsFR      r-o        full
```

What I want is that, no matter how many profiles I have, these will be displayed as an additional column in the results set.  Like if, say we add a new profil, Director, in the profil table and configure the rights in the ProfilRights table, this will display another column, on the right of Admin in the result set.

I have tried doing the below query but it does not work:

```
SELECT P.ProfilName, AT.TranslatedLabel,  PR.Right
FROM ProfilRights PR
INNER JOIN Profil P ON PR.PofilId = P.PofilId
INNER JOIN Access A ON PR.AccessId = A.AccessId
INNER JOIN AccessTranslation [AT] ON A.AccessId = AT.AccessId;
```

However, this is returning me the results as below:

```
 ProfilName    TranslatedLabel     Right
 -----------   --------------      ------
 Admin         EmployeesFR         none
 Admin         ClientsFR           full        
 Admin         Employees           none
 Admin         Clients             full                
 IT            EmployeesFR         full        
 IT            ClientsFR           r-o        
 IT            Employees           full        
 IT            Clients             r-o
```

Please help on how to return the above results set?

Comment: What you want here is conditional aggregation. I *hope* you only have the 2 languages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

```
DECLARE @Counter INT;
DECLARE @totalCount INT;

-- Generate query for accessId and Language mapping temp resultSet

-- Get distinct Language values and store in a temp table
DECLARE @distinctLanguage TABLE (rn INT IDENTITY,Languages VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @distinctLanguage(Languages) (SELECT DISTINCT Languages FROM Translation);


DECLARE @languageQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @totalCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM @distinctLanguage);

SET @Counter = @totalCount;

WHILE (@counter>0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @languageName NVARCHAR(20) = (SELECT Languages FROM @distinctLanguage WHERE rn=@counter);

  IF @counter <> @totalCount SET @languageQuery = CONCAT(@languageQuery,' FULL OUTER JOIN ') 
  
  SET @languageQuery = CONCAT(@languageQuery,' (SELECT AccessId, TranslatedLabel AS ',@languageName,'Access FROM Translation WHERE Languages = ''',@languageName,''')','sq',@counter,' ');
  
  IF @counter <> @totalCount SET @languageQuery = CONCAT(@languageQuery,' ON (sq',@totalCount,'.AccessId=sq',@counter,'.AccessId) ') 

  SET @counter = @counter - 1;

END

DECLARE @allLanguageString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @allLanguageString = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(Languages,'Access'),',') FROM @distinctLanguage);

SET @languageQuery = CONCAT(' SELECT ',@allLanguageString,', sq',@totalCount,'.AccessId FROM ', @languageQuery);


-- Generate query for accessId and profileName mapping temp resultSet

-- Get distinct Profile values and store in a temp table
DECLARE @distinctProfiles TABLE (rn INT IDENTITY,ProfilName VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @distinctProfiles(ProfilName) (SELECT DISTINCT ProfilName FROM Profil);

DECLARE @profileQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @totalCount = (SELECT count(*) FROM @distinctProfiles);

SET @Counter = @totalCount;

WHILE (@counter>0)
BEGIN
  DECLARE @profileName NVARCHAR(20) = (SELECT ProfilName FROM @distinctProfiles WHERE rn=@counter);

  IF @counter <> @totalCount SET @profileQuery = CONCAT(@profileQuery,' FULL OUTER JOIN ') 

  SET @profileQuery = CONCAT(@profileQuery,' (SELECT AccessId, Rights AS ',@profileName,' FROM @profilRights WHERE ProfilName = ''',@profileName,''')','sq',@counter,' ');
  
  IF @counter <> @totalCount SET @profileQuery = CONCAT(@profileQuery,' ON (sq',@totalCount,'.AccessId=sq',@counter,'.AccessId) ') 

  SET @counter = @counter - 1;

END

DECLARE @allProfileString NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @allProfileString = (SELECT STRING_AGG(ProfilName,',') FROM @distinctProfiles);

SET @profileQuery = CONCAT(' SELECT ',@allProfileString,', sq',@totalCount,'.AccessId FROM ', @profileQuery);


-- Construct final query
DECLARE @finalQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @finalQuery = CONCAT(' SELECT ' ,@allLanguageString, ', ',@allProfileString,' FROM ( ',@languageQuery,' ) a FULL OUTER JOIN ( ',@profileQuery,' ) b ON (a.AccessId=b.AccessId)');


-- Create a temp table for profile, accessId and rights mapping
DECLARE @profileRightMappingQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @profileRightMappingQuery= 'DECLARE @profilRights TABLE (ProfilName VARCHAR(20), AccessId INT, Rights VARCHAR(20)); INSERT INTO @profilRights(ProfilName, AccessId, Rights) SELECT ProfilName, AccessId,Rights FROM ProfilRights a LEFT JOIN Profil b ON(a.ProfilId=b.ProfilId);';

SET @finalQuery = CONCAT(@profileRightMappingQuery,' ',@finalQuery);

execute(@finalQuery);
```

**EXPLANATION**

*DISCLAIMER*

- In my opinion, following solution is sql-gymnastics. For the sake of simplicity, performance and maintenance, I would recommended to solve this problem using some code. First bring the request dataset in your application and construct the result there.
- This query is using `STRING_AGG` function to convert rows of a table to comma-separated string. This function is available for version >=`SQL Server 2017`. In case you are using earlier version, you might need to do that manually.
- Though I have tested the query, still some minor edge cases might have been left.

***So that being said, let's start with the explanation.***

Following is the static query that would give you the desired result.

```
DECLARE @profilRights TABLE (ProfilName VARCHAR(20), AccessId INT, Rights VARCHAR(20)); 

INSERT INTO @profilRights(ProfilName, AccessId, Rights)
SELECT ProfilName, AccessId,Rights
FROM ProfilRights a
LEFT JOIN Profil b ON(a.ProfilId=b.ProfilId);


SELECT EnglishAccess, FrenchAccess, IT, Admin
FROM
(
  SELECT EnglishAccess,FrenchAccess,a.AccessId
  FROM
   (
    SELECT AccessId,TranslatedLabel AS 'EnglishAccess' FROM Translation WHERE Languages='English'
   )a FULL OUTER JOIN
   (
    SELECT AccessId,TranslatedLabel AS 'FrenchAccess' FROM Translation WHERE Languages='French'
   )b ON (a.AccessId = b.AccessId)
) a FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT a.AccessId, IT, Admin
  FROM
   (
    SELECT AccessId, Rights AS 'IT' FROM @profilRights WHERE ProfilName = 'IT'
   )a FULL OUTER JOIN
   (
    SELECT AccessId, Rights AS 'Admin' FROM @profilRights WHERE ProfilName = 'Admin'
   ) b ON (a.AccessId=b.AccessId)
) b ON (a.AccessId=b.AccessId)
```

But this query has hard-coded values, so your requirement is not completely fulfilled.

So we simply need to write code to make this query dynamic. To do that, I followed the below algorithm.

```
- Generate query for accessId and Language mapping temp resultSet.
- Generate query for accessId and profileName mapping temp resultSet.
- Construct final query.
- Create a temp table for profile, accessId and rights mapping.
- Execute the final query.
```

***DDL Script***

```
CREATE TABLE ProfilRights(ProfilRightId INT,ProfilId INT,AccessId INT, RIGHTS VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO ProfilRights(ProfilRightId, ProfilId ,AccessId , RIGHTS)
VALUES (1, 1,1,'full'),
(2, 1, 2,'r-o'),
(3, 2, 1,'none'),
(4, 2, 2,'full')


CREATE TABLE Profil(ProfilId INT, ProfilName VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO Profil(ProfilId , ProfilName)
VALUES (1, 'IT'),
(2, 'Admin')



CREATE TABLE Access(AccessId INT, AccessName VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO Access(AccessId , AccessName)
VALUES (1, 'Employess'),
(2, 'Clients')



CREATE TABLE Translation(AccessTransId INT, AccessId INT, TranslatedLabel VARCHAR(20), Languages VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO Translation(AccessTransId , AccessId , TranslatedLabel , Languages)
VALUES (1, 1,'Employess','English'),
(2, 2,'Clients','English'),
(3, 1,'EmployeesFR','French'),
(4, 2,'ClientsFR','French')
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, i would use dynamic query + PIVOT.

Here is an article that explains how to do it: [Dynamic Pivot](https://sqlskull.com/2020/06/16/sql-server-dynamic-pivot/)